# Blur function, set the last value

Tags: javascript, jquery, blur

On my inputs I have a function which remove the value of the inputs when the user click on it.
For that, no problem.

I'm trying to write a function to "rewrite" in the input fields, the last known value if the user didn't fill it on blur.

It works fine when I have only **one input** using the following code :

```
    $("input").blur(function() {

    if ($(this).val().length != 0){}

    else{    
    $("#angleplansup1").val(parameters5.a1);                        
    }
}
```

);

```
    parameters5.a1 = Number($('#angleplansup1').val());
```

The problem is I have a lot of inputs and It doesn't work when I put all off them because, they all change... (that's logical).

So, and I'm searching a way to put the last known value.

```
        $("input").blur(function() {

    if ($(this).val().length != 0){}

    else{    
    $(this).val("the last known value");                        
    }
}
```

);

I tried unsuccesfully to use `document.activeElement` but it doesn't seems to work with blur.

Another way would be to automatize a kind of switch or array, but I'm not skilled enough to think on it yet and I would have your view on this.
Here is my code with other variables if it can help.
Thank you very much.
Have a nice day.

```
$("input").blur(function() {

    if ($(this).val().length != 0){}

    else{    
        $("#hauteuraxe1").val(parameters5.h);
        $("#angleplansup1").val(parameters5.a1);            
        $("#grandehauteur2").val(parameters5.gh);           
        $("#delta2").val(parameters5.delta);            
        $("#petitehauteur3").val(parameters5.ph);           
        ...
        ..
        .
    }
});



    parameters5.h = Number($('#hauteuraxe1').val());    
    parameters5.a1 = Number($('#angleplansup1').val());
    parameters5.gh = Number($('#grandehauteur2').val());
    parameters5.delta = Number($('#delta2').val());
    parameters5.ph = Number($('#petitehauteur3').val());
    ...
    ..
    .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first you need to hold your values. For that I create an object `values` which holds the values like `'id' : 'value"`. After every `blur` if there is a value, I store the text in the `values`. If after `blur` there is no value, I set the previous one.

**See the example**

```js
var values = {};

$('input').on('blur', function(e){
  var target = e.currentTarget;
  
  if(target.value){
    values[target.id] = target.value
  } else {
    target.value = values[target.id];
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="a" />
<input id="b" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Suren, it doesn't work because I have a lot of code, but I understand some things and it will be usefull

Comment: I give you an shared logic how you can do it

Comment: So, I got it, thank you very much Suren ;)
Have a nice day !